# Parallel processing in node js function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that has more than 1400+ crypto pairs and I have to send an API against each pair and store the trades. Now each pair takes 3-4 seconds hence the whole function takes a lot of time. I am getting the pairs from my DB and I am storing trade data in my DB as well. I need to process the pairs in parallel so the trades from the pair in the beginning don't miss because the function is not processing.

This is my current function:

```
const getTrades = async () => {
  let page = 1;
  const results = await db.query("SELECT * FROM pairs;");
  const pairs = results.rows;
  const latest = await db.query("SELECT MAX(trade_time) FROM trades");
  const latestTrade = latest.rows[0].max;
  const coinResult = await db.query("SELECT * FROM coins");
  let coinsInfo = coinResult.rows;
  coinsInfo = coinsInfo.flat();
  for (const pair of pairs) {
    let biggestTrade = [];
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/trades?symbol=${pair.pair}`
    );
    let filtered = response.data;
    filtered = filtered.filter((trade) => trade.time > latestTrade);
    let sells = filtered.filter((trade) => trade.isBuyerMaker === true);
    let buys = filtered.filter((trade) => trade.isBuyerMaker === false);
    if (sells.length > 0) {
      biggestTrade.push(
        sells.reduce(function (prev, current) {
          return prev.quoteQty > current.quoteQty ? prev : current;
        })
      );
    }
    if (buys.length > 0) {
      biggestTrade.push(
        buys.reduce(function (prev, current) {
          return prev.quoteQty > current.quoteQty ? prev : current;
        })
      );
    }

    biggestTrade = biggestTrade.flat();
    for (const trade of filtered) {
      let priceUSD = 0;
      let baseAssetIcon = "null";
      for (const coin of coinsInfo) {
        if (coin.symbol.toUpperCase() === pair.quote_asset) {
          priceUSD = coin.current_price;
        }
        if (coin.symbol.toUpperCase() === pair.base_asset) {
          baseAssetIcon = coin.image_url;
        }
        if (priceUSD > 0 && baseAssetIcon != "null") {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (trade.quoteQty * priceUSD > 50000) {
        const results = db.query(
          "INSERT INTO trades (exchange_name, exchange_icon_url, trade_time, price_in_quote_asset,price_in_usd, trade_value, base_asset_icon,  qty, quoteQty, is_buyer_maker, pair, base_asset_trade, quote_asset_trade) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12, $13)",
          [
            "Binance",
            "https://assets.coingecko.com/markets/images/52/small/binance.jpg?1519353250",
            trade.time,
            trade.price,
            priceUSD,
            trade.quoteQty * priceUSD,
            baseAssetIcon,
            trade.qty,
            trade.quoteQty,
            trade.isBuyerMaker,
            pair.pair,
            pair.base_asset,
            pair.quote_asset,
          ]
        );
        console.log("TRADE ADDED");
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("PAIRS ARE OVER");
};

pairs has over 1400 entries and this is the one where are looping through.
```

Comment: If you are ok with a package, [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastq) is awesome. If you dont want to use it, you can browse the code

Comment: Can you guide me on how to use this package on my function?

Comment: Does this help you? https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

depends on how many servers you are running this function on.

if it's one single machine, use worker_threads, basically run the same function in separate threads to achieve parallelization, but to be honest, 1400 pairs are a lot, each for 3-4 seconds, so total around 1-2hrs per run if in serial. Depending on your machines, if you have 8 cores, it might reduce the time by 8 folds but still leave you like around 10 minutes. and cloud service usually charge a lot more for instances that have more cpu cores.

if it's multiple machines, use a master and a queue to push new pairs to each worker machine and for each worker machine, you can also generate multiple threads for each machine, in that way you can scale horizontally, and it's possible to finish the run in seconds. in this situation, each machine you can get the cheap one from cloud providers.

so depends on your requirements, if you wanna super fast, you gotta add more machines.